# Slow ethernet connection Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu (previously Windows 10 machine) and everything seems to work fine except for ethernet. When downloading, I get max 1.2MB/s, while previously on Windows I was used to up to 10MB/s (note that no hardware was changed or manipulated, so I'm pretty sure it's some software problem). Also when using wi-fi, my connection seems normal, like it was on windows (but I don't wanna use wi-fi, because it's slower and unstable).

Now I'm pretty inexperienced user, but I figured out you might want to see these

```
    andrew@andrew-UX360UA:~$ ethtool enx00e04c4400f4 
Settings for enx00e04c4400f4:
Supported ports: [ MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 32
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
Current message level: 0x00007fff (32767)
               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued      intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol
Link detected: yes



andrew@andrew-UX360UA:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for andrew: 
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 59
   serial: a4:02:b9:46:c6:61
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.1.210 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 memory:df000000-df001fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: enx00e04c4400f4
   serial: 00:e0:4c:44:00:f4
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v2.10.00 (2018/03/16) duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

Thanks for help. 
EDIT: I also tried disabling IPv6, no difference.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As you can see, your interface negotiated 10Mbps (`Speed: 10Mb/s` from the output of `ethtool`). That's in line with the downloads speed you get (10Mbit/s ~ 1.25 MByte/s). I suspect a problem with the card itself OR the switch. Try plugging it in a different port.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. I forgot to mention that I'm using an USB ethernet adapter, but when using the cable and adapter on another computer, it works as expected